# 'Undefined is not an object' when evaluating a redux action (this.props.function) on new screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an app with three tabs (using react-navigation v2). On one tab, I have a button called 'settings' that leads the user to the settings screen by way of the following.

```
<Button
 transparent
 danger
 onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
>
 <Text>Settings</Text>
</Button>
```

If I play around with the app and click through different screens, no error occurs and I am able to navigate to the settings screen just fine. However, if I just reloaded the app, navigate to the appropriate tab and click on the settings button, I get the following error:

[image: Settings Screen Navigation Error]

The method refered to in the error (this.props.fetchAdminSettings) is a method in the SettingsScreen class I am trying to navigate to. The relevant code for the SettingsScreen class is shown below.

```
import {
  fetchAdminSettings,
  logout
} from '../../actions';

class SettingsScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Settings',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff'
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.willFocus);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.willFocusSubscription) {
      this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
    }
  }

  willFocus() {
    this.props.fetchAdminSettings(this.props.organization);
  }

         .
         .
[some render methods]
         .
         .

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 50 }}>
              <Text style={{ fontColor: 'red', fontSize: 10 }}>
                {this.props.errorMessage}
              </Text>
              {this.renderAdminSettings(this.props.admin)}
              {this.renderUserSettings()}
            </View>
          </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { organization, rank, firstName, lastName, admin } = state.auth;

  const { loadingAdminSettings,
    securityCode,
    totalBrotherhoods,
    totalChapters,
    totalCommunityService,
    totalDues,
    totalMixers,
    errorMessage
  } = state.settings;

  return ({
    organization,
    rank,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    admin,
    loadingAdminSettings,
    securityCode,
    totalBrotherhoods,
    totalChapters,
    totalCommunityService,
    totalDues,
    totalMixers,
    errorMessage
  });
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchAdminSettings,
  logout
})(SettingsScreen);
```

**EDIT**
And the fetchAdminSettings action creator is as follows:

```
export const fetchAdminSettings = (organization) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ADMIN_SETTINGS });
    firebase.database().ref(`${organization}/admin`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ADMIN_SETTINGS_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
    });
  };
};
```

Any help you could give me would be appreciated!

Comment: It is hard to answer your question without the implementation details of `fetchAdminSettings`

Comment: @Backslash36 I've edited the post to include the implementation of fetchAdminSettings. I feel as if the issue is not the function itself, but rather the function call in the SettingsScreen class

Comment: Thanks ! I think I see the problem. I'll answer you in a bit

Answer (score 0):

You passed an object as the second argument to the `connect` call.

As [the doc](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) states, each field in such an object must be an action creator. An [action creator](https://redux.js.org/glossary#action-creator) is a function that should return an action. Instead, you are returning a function that accepts dispatch as argument.

Shouldn't it rather be something like this ?

```
//...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchAdminSettings(organization) {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_ADMIN_SETTINGS });
      firebase.database().ref(`${organization}/admin`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_ADMIN_SETTINGS_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
      });
    },
    logout() {
      // ...
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SettingsScreen);
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't believe this is the issue. I've set up all my screens in the same manner where each of my redux actions is mapped to props in the second argument of the connect function. It hasn't thrown any errors in the other cases. 

The error does not occur when I navigate to other screens on the tab and then click on the settings button. Strangely, this only occurs when I navigate straight to the settings button from launch

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

I'm not entirely sure why, but the code I use to rerender a screen on Focus (shown below) was the source of the issue.

I instead ran the 'fetchAdminSettings' function in componentWillMount() by itself and it worked.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.willFocus);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.willFocusSubscription) {
      this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
    }
  }

  willFocus() {
    this.props.fetchAdminSettings(this.props.organization);
  }
```